# MAMP localhost include and cookie setting functionality

Tags: php, cookies, include, localhost, mamp

I am trying to move my site offline for obvious reasons and I am having trouble getting the `localhost` PHP function to work. My code is the following:

```
include "http://localhost:8888/mainbar.php?display=1";
```

I am able to include the file if I just have it's name, but I need to pass values over the url so this is not an option. I have looked into other means of getting this to work, but the whole point of using MAMP is to be able to work offline and then upload improvements.

Next, I am unable to set cookies. Here is the following cookie code I have:

```
$expire=time() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60);
setcookie("user", "Conan", $expire, '/');
```

I also have tried to set cookies with Chrome but am unable to do so.I would be surprised if this cannot be done.

Comment: Typically including is done on local files, not through a web server. When you include through http, what's happening is that PHP is acting as a web browser of sorts and making a second request to the server.  Is that actually what you want to do?  It seems like you might just want to pass a variable through to the include.  `$display = 'foo';` then in the include, `$display` is still foo.  I feel like I'm missing something though?  There seems to be a bad design or a misunderstanding of `include` going on here.

Comment: Instead of `include` why not just use `echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/mainbar.php?display=1')`? Unless it contains php code itself, which is a pretty bad idea. In fact, the whole thing is a bad idea, because whatever's inside `mainbar.php` should just be called from within this code.

Comment: Is your time proper on your localhost?

Comment: @Corbin actually mate it is perfectly legal to use the full url.

Comment: @Pete it's legal in the same way that hammering a nail with a shoe is legal.  You can do it, but it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Includes should only be given file paths, not URLs.

The proper usage would look like the following:
include "/path/to/file"

`include "/var/www/html/yourappfolder/mainbar.php";`

I see that you are trying to pass it a variable, `?display=1`. The solution wouldn't be to figure out how to load the file with a URL parameter, you really want to redesign how your fetching the information that corresponds to the `display` variable.

What you want to do is improve the software design and create a separate function somewhere, something like: `getMainBarData($display)`. In your mainbar.php file, you will call this function to get the results you currently have. In your file that you're using include, you can include the file holding the new function `getMainBarData($display)`, and call it directly: `getMainBarData(1)`.

So basically, you want to create a function that is both usable by `mainbar.php` and this file using include. 1 function that can be used by 2 pages is your optimal solution here.

As far as the cookie issue.. Try without the path "/".. so:

`setcookie('user', 'Conan', $expire);`

Comment: Random pickiness: using hard coded full paths is a huge pain waiting to happen.  Much easier to either `define()` a base path, use careful relative paths, or lots of `__DIR__` usage.  (Not that you particularly said that he should use a hard coded full path, but beginners tend to pick up bad habits very easily :(.)

Comment: I completely agree, and I do that as well. For simplicity's sake, I didn't want to add any extra layers of confusion if that isn't already a familiar concept

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question you need to have url_file_include enabled.This is considered a huge security risk and in general it should never ever be used, as it is a sign of bad design.In order to make this work you just have to add an

```
allow_url_include=1
```

in your php.ini.
For the later part of the question your code works ok on my MAMP installation so you have to make sure that your call to setcookie is before any output to the browser (any echo).
Also you should consider not using cookies if you are going to save any sensitive information.

Comment: Yea - this is definitely an alternative, but not one you just consider. It's a quick shortcut rather than not addressing proper software design, along with the big security risk it poses.